# Definition of a Period 2-orbit

Tags: chaos-theory

In my text and notes, the term "period 2-orbit" and "period 2 doubling to chaos" is used but without a definition given.

Can someone provide a definition for what period 2-orbit is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The phrase "period 2-orbit" makes little sense to me. If you'd asked about the meaning of "period-2 orbit" I'd say that was an orbit of period $2$... ($(f^n(x))$ where it happens that $f^{n+2}(x)=f^n(x)$.)

Comment: That "-" could be a typological error in the notes. 
So in general, a period-N orbit occurs where $f^{n+N}=f^{n}$, is this correct?@DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the context to say that's _correct_, but that's what I would assume it meant until it became clear it must mean something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually in terms of chaos theory this the used definition [period doubling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period-doubling_bifurcation)

A period doubling cascade is a sequence of doublings and further doublings of the repeating period, as the parameter is adjusted further and further.

A period n orbit is  akin to an identity  map after every n iterations.

often accompanied by the limit of the ratio of distance of period doublings

Comment: I could be wrong but intuition says the a period N-orbit is sort of akin to an identity map after every N iteration.

Comment: your probably right, sorry group theory and chaos theory hard to swith,similar terms

Comment: it could also be the level of the recursion for instance a recursion based of of xn and xn-1 is degree 2 where Lucas series are degree 3.